# C++ removing an std::function from a std::vector<std::function<...>>

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following system of callbacks

```
class ... {

    ...

    std::vector<std::function<void()>>        systemBringUps;
    std::vector<std::function<void()>>        systemTearDowns;
    std::vector<std::function<void(EntityID_t)>> systemMains;
    std::vector<std::function<bool(EntityID_t)>> systemChecks;

    template <typename T>
    void registerSystem() {
        systemBringUps.push_back(T::systemBringUp);
        systemTearDowns.push_back(T::systemTearDown);
        systemMains.push_back(T::systemMain);
        systemChecks.push_back(T::systemCheck);
        T::onSystemRegister();
    }

    template <typename T>
    void deregisterSystem() {
        std::function<void()> bringUp = T::systemBringUp;
        std::function<void()> tearDown = T::systemTearDown;
        std::function<void(EntityID_t)> smain = T::systemMain;
        std::function<bool(EntityID_t)> check = T::systemCheck;

        std::remove(systemBringUps.begin(), systemBringUps.end(), bringUp);
        std::remove(systemTearDowns.begin(), systemTearDowns.end(), tearDown);
        std::remove(systemMains.begin(), systemMains.end(), smain);
        std::remove(systemChecks.begin(), systemChecks.end(), check);
        T::onSystemDeregister();
    }
```

The `registerSystem` template function works fine, but the `deregisterSystem` function fails to compile, stating

```
...

/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../include/c++/7.5.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:241:17: error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('std::function<bool (unsigned short)>' and 'const std::function<bool (unsigned short)>')
        { return *__it == _M_value; }
                 ~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~
...
```

So it seems that `std::remove` cannot compile since the `std::function`s in `deregisterSystem` that I am defining are `const`, whereas those in the vectors I am trying to remove from are not? Is there any way I can discard the `const` qualifier from these `std::function`s? I have tried using the copy constructor as in

```
template <typename T>
    void deregisterSystem() {
        std::function<void()> bringUp(T::systemBringUp);
        std::function<void()> tearDown(T::systemTearDown);
        std::function<void(EntityID_t)> smain(T::systemMain);
        std::function<bool(EntityID_t)> check(T::systemCheck);

        std::remove(systemBringUps.begin(), systemBringUps.end(), bringUp);
        std::remove(systemTearDowns.begin(), systemTearDowns.end(), tearDown);
        std::remove(systemMains.begin(), systemMains.end(), smain);
        std::remove(systemChecks.begin(), systemChecks.end(), check);
        T::onSystemDeregister();
    }
```

but this fails in a similar way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::function<F>::target`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) to get the held function object directly and compare that.

For example, to erase all of the functions that are `T::systemBringUp` in `systemBringUps`, you could do something like:

```cpp
systemBringUps.erase(std::remove_if(systemBringUps.begin(), systemBringUps.end(), [](const auto& f) {
    auto* target = f.template target<decltype(T::systemBringUp)>();
    return target != nullptr && *target == T::systemBringUp;
}), systemBringUps.end());
```

You can make a helper function to check if a `std::function` is holding a value:

```cpp
template<class F, class T>
bool is_function_holding(const std::function<F>& func, const T& target) {
    static_assert(std::is_assignable<std::function<F>&, const T&>::value, "Function could not possibly hold target");
    auto* current_target = func.template target<typename std::decay<T>::type>();
    return current_target != nullptr && *current_target == target;
}

// Later
systemBringUps.erase(std::remove_if(systemBringUps.begin(), systemBringUps.end(), [](const auto& f) {
    return is_function_holding(f, T::systemBringUp);
}, systemBringUps.end());
systemTearDowns.erase(std::remove_if(systemTearDowns.begin(), systemTearDowns.end(), [](const auto& f) {
    return is_function_holding(f, T::systemTearDown);
}, systemTearDowns.end());
// ...
```

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks for giving some example implementations!

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is not constness but that that `std::function` objects can not be compared for equality at all. Your current approach simply will not work.

The solution is to give some sort of unique 'token' during registration to the caller which can be used to unregister later.

Comment: Oh, that's me not knowing enough C++! Thanks a lot for the tip